# Replace a string, with another, when the first starts and ends with specific string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, random

I have a few strings in `PHP` that are like this
`"abc167828xyz"`, where the numbers in the middle are generated by random. Now I want to replace every string that starts with `"abc"` and ends with `"xyz"` with another one. Remember that the numbers are generated by random!

Is not a duplicate. I want to replace strings, NOT to find files. Sorry but I am new in PHP

Code:

```
<?php
$string1 = "hey abcdef abc266299xyz xyzxyz there";
echo str_replace(array("hey", "abcdef", "xyzxyz", "there"), "replaced", $string1);
```

I want to include `abc266299xyz` to the array and replace it like the others. 
The result should be `replaced replaced replaced replaced replaced`
PS this is an example, not my real code

Comment: You want to replace `abc` and `xyz` with another on each. For example, you have a string `abc167828xyz`, once it is replaced, it will look like `def167828wxy`? or want to remove them leaving only the number?

Comment: I want to replace the whole string, with numbers and letters

Comment: Can you provide some examples to ease us understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Get a string that starts and ends with a specific string, and replace the whole string with another.

Comment: You can do that with just `str_replace` function like `str_replace($string_to_be_replaced, $string_replacement, $str)` if you want to replace the whole string.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to regex. I know how to replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `/abc\d+xyz/` where `\d+` means one or more digit.

```
$re = '/(abc\d+xyz|hey|abcdef|xyzxyz|there)/';
$str = 'lorem abc167828xyz ipsum abc167828xyz dolores';
$subst = 'AnotherString';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

---

`/(abc\d+xyz|hey|abcdef|xyzxyz|there)/` will match any of the pipe separated value, replace with your real strings.

Comment: There is a problem. I used `str_replace` to replace some normal strings, and I need to replace normal strings and regex strings at once. I can't use `preg_replace` to do that

Comment: You should edit your question with this information and provide some code you already use @Jakeashacks

Comment: It says `Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: It doesn't work.  Should I give you my actual code??

Comment: What I am doing is: Get all the links from a page, and by replacing I am taking one of them. So the string includes `'`, `/`, `:`, `:`, `-`

Comment: @Jakeashacks your escape of `/` is incorrect, that's why you get the error. Could you provide a list of the raw string you want to replace?

Comment: There is no benefit to using a capture group in the pattern.